# Does the definition of a virtual member function force dynamic initialization of a static data member in the same translation unit?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Consider the following two translation units:

```
// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  virtual ~Foo() = default;

  virtual void bar();

private:
  static int _baz;
};


static int f() {
  std::cout << "f called\n";
  return 42;
}

int Foo::_baz = f();

void Foo::bar() {
  std::cout << "Baz::bar called\n";
}
```

and

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "main called\n";
}
```

When compiling both translation units into a single executable (e.g. with `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp foo.cpp`, choice of optimization level or ordering of the two cpp files doesn't matter), the resulting executable prints

> f called
>     main called

regardless of which of the three major compilers GCC, clang and MSVC was used to compile it. You can see the behaviour for yourself on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/23XfBP72fIPz1oMG).

My question is: Does the standard guarantee that `Foo::_baz` will be initialized (and thus `f` will be called) *even if the entire class `Foo` isn't used in the program at all*?

I believe this to be the case; my reasoning goes as follows:

According to [[basic.start.dynamic]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#dynamic-4), `Foo::_baz` doesn't have to be initialized before the first statement of main is executed, but

> if [the initialization] is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Here, "non-initialization odr-use" is defined as

> [...] an odr-use ([basic.def.odr]) not caused directly or indirectly by the initialization of a non-local static or thread storage duration variable

in [[basic.start.dynamic]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#dynamic-3). But as per [[basic.def.odr]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#7),

> a virtual member function is odr-used if it is not pure.

from which I conclude that the definition of `Foo::bar` is a non-initialization odr-use of a non-inline function defined in the same translation unit as `Foo::_baz`, and thus `Foo::_baz` will be initialized.

What I find odd about this line of reasoning is that the deferred initialization of `Foo::_baz` would need to happen before the odr-use of `Foo::bar`, i.e. before `Foo::bar` is defined (wtf?!) since the definition alone is an odr-use. This makes me think my reasoning might be flawed.

So again: Does the standard guarantee that `Foo::_baz` will be initialized (and thus `f` will be called) *even if nothing in its translation unit is ever used in the program at all*? If yes, is there something we can say about *when* this will happen (given the weird ordering constraint that it has to happen before the virtual member function is defined), and if no, where's the error in my reasoning?

Comment: Same output if no virtual functions are involved. And the code you posted is not compilable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've added the missing semicolon and missing include. It is interesting that there is the same output without the virtual function, I hadn't even tried that because surely that behaviour can't be guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: AFAIK a compiler is fully entitled to force thie initialisation `int Baz::_i = f();`, but if the variable is not actually used anywhere, and there are no side-effects, then the optimiser could remove it. Proving either of those conditions would be extremely difficult, so I would always expect the initialisation to take place. Either way, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with virtual functions.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The compiler is indeed allowed to perform static initialization instead of dynamic initialization here per http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start#static-3 .
But I'm asking whether any standard-conforming implementation is allowed to not call `f`. If my reasoning as written in the question is sound then `f` always has to be called, but I'm not sure I've missed something.

Comment: AFAIK The "as-if" rule says that  if the compiler can prove that a function has no side effects and its return value is not used, then it need not be called. Proving those things in a real program is very difficult, however.

Comment: @NeilButterworth So you agree that in this case of the initializing function having side-effects the standard guarantees that `f` will be called?

Comment: Not at all - my days of spelunking in the standard are long past. But I would be amazed if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

The static initialization is not affected by virtual functions and the relation with dynamic initialization is about ordering, for constant initializers it happens as stated in `[class.static.data]/2`

> [Note: Once the static data member has been defined, it exists even if no objects of its class have been created. ... — end note ]

However `[basic.start.dynamic]/4`

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Even if the implementation choose to defer the initialization, the standard mandate that it happens. and as a footnote of the previous clause:

> A non-local variable with static storage duration having initialization with side effects is initialized in this case, even if it is not itself odr-used.

Comment: I'm aware that the static data member exists even if no objects of the class have been created. The question is whether it also is guaranteed to be initialized. For static initialization the answer is yes, as you said, but since we're dealing with (potentially) dynamic initialization here the  question is more tricky.

Comment: "Even if the implementation choose to defer the initialization, the standard mandate that it happens" Good point. But the question still remains whether it is possible that the program prints "main entered" and then "f entered" because the compiler choose to initialize `Baz::_i` only after `main` has finished executing?

Comment: @Corristo  No, that isn't possible.

Comment: It seems to me that that might happens, deferred initialization model on demand-initialization as `It is implementation-defined whether either a or b is initialized before main is entered or whether the initializations are delayed until a is first odr-used in main.` implies, yet, this is implementation dependent, but either way the side effects of initialization occurs.

Comment: My understanding is all static data is initisalised, whether statically or dynamically. The key point being because main() is in the same translation unit. If you had a different translation unit, execution never reached it, then statics may not be initialised.

Comment: @SJHowe In my example the statics are deliberately not in the same translation unit as `main`. That's why I asked whether they're guaranteed to be initialized *even though they're in a different translation unit and actually never used*.

Comment: @Corristo  "In my example the statics are deliberately not in the same translation unit as main" - yes they are - a comment aside! Please will you take some time and effort to post some code that _clearly_ illustrates what you are asking about. I would suggest deleting this question and starting again. You should also post information on how you are building this program.

Comment: @Corristo: As Neil says. You posted code which *showed* main() in the same translation unit as your class where static data is dynamically initialised. If you meant otherwise - _then your code is misleading_. If you have a 2nd translation unit, and execution path *never* goes in that unit, then any static data in that 2nd translation unit *won't* be initialised.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I included the information on how I built the executable, made the distinction of the two translation units clearer and simplified the code. I can't delete the question though as it already has an answer.

Comment: @SJHowe: I've edited the question to make it clearer that there are two translation units. Your statement "If you have a 2nd translation unit, and execution path never goes in that unit, then any static data in that 2nd translation unit won't be initialised" is incorrect, though, as the variable indeed gets initialized. So my question is: Is it *guaranteed* to be initialized by the standard or does it just so happen that all three major compilers agree and initialize it even though they don't have to? If not, where has my reasoning presented in the question gone wrong?

Comment: Corristo. I think you are right. I have changed my mind. If you look at your class definition, it could be in a .H file would could be included in another translation unit. It could be inherited from. Your class could be called from a 3rd translation unit. Could _baz() and f() be optimised out? Yes it could. Could the class be dropped? Yes if a linker did some type of global analysis. From the point of view of a the standard, dynamic initialisation occurs before main() (or deferred but immediately after). The answer to this topic question is "no".

Comment: A smart compiler and linker could see your static data is private, see that none of the class deals with it and so optimises it out.